# Form submission on time interval in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<?php
$time=60;
$questionid=7;
$answered="false";

$servername = "***";
$dbusername = "***";
$dbpassword = "*****";
$dbname= "***";
$sub="***";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
$mysql="SELECT answered,ansstr,timespnt FROM question_data WHERE questionid='$questionid' and subject='$sub' limit 1";
$oldresult=$conn->execute_query($mysql);
$value = $oldresult->fetch_object();
if (isset($_POST["submitButton"]) || isset($_POST["submitted"])){
    $updata=$_POST["updata"];
      if(isset($_POST["timespnt"]))
      $timetosend=$_POST["timespnt"];
      else $timetosend=0;
  
      if(isset($_POST["answered"]))  
      $anstosend=$_POST["answered"];
      else $anstosend='false';
  
  $upsql="UPDATE question_data SET answered='$anstosend', ansstr='$updata', timespnt='$timetosend' WHERE questionid='$questionid'";
    $conn->execute_query($upsql);  
}
$answered=$value->answered;
$timetaken=$value->timespnt;
$time=60-$timetaken;
?>
<head>
<body>
<div id='timer'></div>
<form method="POST" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'?questionid='.$questionid;?> style='margin:auto;text-align:center' id="send" >
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="timespnt" value="<?php echo $timetaken;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="updata" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="answered" value="false" />
<?php if($answered !='true') 
echo '<input name="submitButton" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">';
?>
</form>
<?php

?>

</head>
</body>
<script>
var Timer;
var TotalSeconds;
const form = document.getElementById('send');

function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time) {
    Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
    TotalSeconds = Time;
    UpdateTimer();
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);}

function Tick() {
    TotalSeconds -= 1;
    form.querySelector('[name=timespnt]').value =TotalSeconds;
    if(TotalSeconds==0){
    //alert(0+' alert!!!');
    form.querySelector('[name=answered]').value ="true";
    form.submit();   
    } 
    
    else{
    UpdateTimer()
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}
}

    function UpdateTimer() {
    Timer.innerHTML = TotalSeconds;
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let tId;
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    clearTimeout(tId);
    form.querySelector('[name=submitted]').value = 'formsubmit';
    form.querySelector('[name=updata]').value =userchoice.toString();
    form.querySelector('[name=answered]').value ="true";
});
  tId = setTimeout(() => form.submit(),1*60*1000); 
});

var userchoice=['a','b','c'];

<?php
if($answered=='false')
echo 'window.onload = CreateTimer("timer",'. $time.');';
else echo 'document.write("Submission Completed");';
?>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is:--

I have this form of id `send`. Now, here I have an array named `userchoice` that I want to be passed and stored into my database. Now, after 1 minute, the form would be auto submitted, the variable `answered` in the database would be set to `true` and I would show the user a different content based on it. But if somehow, the user reloads the page, then the form gets auto submitted and in my database but the time in my page does not remain unchanged [though I am storing it in my database, so that the time counting is not hampered]. It suddenly shifts to a different value, but why?

Moreover, if I press the submit button, the variable in the database `answered` was supposed to be set `true` but it remains false. If I press again, then it sets to `true`. I think I am having some problem with the structure of my code, most probably the arrangement. But what that could be? I am confused with the set up of the code.

Comment: @Teemu what do you mean by the first `if` in PHP. `if (isset($_POST["submitButton"]) || isset($_POST["submitted"]))` -this?

Comment: It looks like it was a bit hasty comment, `button`s not type of `submit` are not send.

Comment: @Teemu But I have a input type of `submit`. Does not that work?

Comment: You are setting `$answered` with `$answered=$value->answered;`, which relies on `$object`, which comes from a query which was executed _before_ you did the `UPDATE` query. Therefore it doesn't take into account the most recent data which was submitted. In the same way `$time` is also based on that old data.

Comment: @ADyson Ok, I understand. Any suggestion on how to change that? Or do I need to shift to cookies then? As I can see, the update function runs before the line `$answered=$value->answered` is executed? Then, why does not it takes into account the most recent data which was submitted.

Comment: Just run the UPDATE before you run the SELECT. Simple.

Comment: `As I can see, the update function runs before the line $answered=$value->answered is executed? Then, why does not it takes into account the most recent data which was submitted`...I already explained why that is in my first comment. $answered is relying on the results of the SELECT query which ran before the UPDATE. It already took the data from the database at that moment. It does not pull any new results from the database after that.

Comment: Aside: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.